# Do you have to append `u` suffix to unsigned integers?

Tags: c, variables, literals, unsigned

I know the `u` suffix means 'unsigned'. But is in *necessary* in the following code?

```
uint32_t hash = 2166136261u;
```

Is it a matter or convention? Or does it have any technical significance in this case? The value should be converted to unsigned anyway because `uint32_t` is unsigned.

When should I and when should I not use the `u` suffix for unsigned integer values?

Answer (score 5):

No it is not necessary. Things get interesting at `2147483648` and your number is greater than this.

Note that formally `2166136261` is a `long` or a `long long` type if `int` has 32 bits or fewer. But either are convertible to a `uint32_t` in a well-defined way.

As a final point: the equivalent hex `0x811C9DC5` is an `unsigned` type if `int` has 32 bits or more. Oh joy!

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant

Comment: I'll just leave it here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5

Comment: @EugeneSh.: And we can add binary literals to the hex and octal case if C gets them. (C++ has from C++14).

Comment: What if `int` is 16 bits long?

Comment: @magras: I just wacked that in. It doesn't matter. `2166136261` would be a `long` or a `long long` if `long` is not long enough. I was longing to write that; now I don't need to wait any longer.

Comment: @Bathsheba wouldn't the rules for binary constants depend on the implementation? As their very existence depends on it...

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It might do, but see the corresponding C++ page to the link I posted: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: @EugeneSh. So it is not neccessarry since the first one fit in the table you link refers to will be taken. Right?

Comment: @SomeName What is not necessary? Update: Ah, you mean the suffix. Yes, as the answer is stating.